# How to move vpn connection from ubuntu to elementary os

Tags: settings, networking, ubuntu

If i want to export vpn connection from networkmanager (ubuntu) what should i do?
I already copied /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/.nmconnection file into my new elementary installation. But i cant find this connection in settings. What i'm doing/thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What i did is moved all my settings by hand. If you moving openvpn connection, dont forget to also check "advanced settings" and check all tabs there.

[image: Network openvpn advanced settings tls auth tab]